# Eclipse Java - Set compiler to Java 6 but still have Java 7 methods/libraries and no complains

Tags: java, eclipse, compatibility

For a project I must use Java 6, so I set my eclipse compiler setting to 1.6 (JDK compliance level).

However, I included `java.nio.file.Files` which is a Java 7 library and I am not getting any complaints. I can ensure that my project specific setting is set to 1.6. I even changed my entire workspace to 1.6 and rebuilt, still no complaints. My colleagues are seeing the complaint on java.nio.files.

Is it becuase I have a jdk7 which is recognizing the `java.nio.file.Files` even when set to 1.6 spcs?

Comment: By "compiler setting" do you actually mean JDK compliance level?

Comment: @Mena yes exactly,. Project has "Enable project specific settings" checked and compliance set to JavaSE-1.6

Comment: Yes. You should always use a Runtime Library that matches the Java version, so the method signatures will match at runtime. You need to install a Java 6. You can install the Java 6 JDK alone, by deselecting the JRE in the installer.

Comment: Just replicated something similar, with a compliance of 1.6 but building with JDK8: `Path path = Paths.get("/");` compiles. The idea is that this doesn't break Java 6 syntax. Now if I used lambdas, it wouldn't compile obviously.

Comment: @GhostCat no problem, thanks for the quick yet accurate reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different things:

- the *compliance* level is about the **syntax** that you can use when writing Java code (respectively about the Java version number that gets put into compiled byte code)
- but the **libraries** that are available to you depend on the **JDK** that your project is using!

In other words: if you truly want to restrict your project to Java 6 libraries, you will have to install a Java 6 JDK on your system, and point to that within your project setup ( most likely, your current project setup makes use of a newer-than-Java-6 JDK ).

And the usual disclaimer: Java 6 has had end of life many years ago. You should do whatever you can to upgrade your setup.

Answer (score 1):

*JDK compliance level* is the level of the Java syntax, not the runtime libraries. It will just prevent you from using language features that were introduced in later versions like try-with-resources which was introduced in JDK 7.

If you want to develop for JDK6, you need to use JDK6.

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 is able to interpret `java.nio.file.Files` because there is no special Java 7 syntax in contrast to Java 7 and Java 8 (lambda expressions etc.). So you are working on standard libraries. Uninstall Java 7 JDK and install Java 6 JDK and you will that `java.nio.file.Files` is not available anymore.